# What happens if I buy a game I already own through Steam a second time?

Tags: steam

I am debating whether or not to get the Potato Sack (yes, I realize I've been debating for several weeks now) bundle through steam.

I already own: Defense Grid: The Awakening, Super Meat Boy, and Audiosurf, all of which are part of the sack pack. What happens if I buy the Potato Sack?

Do I get 2nd copies of the three above mentioned games to gift elsewhere?

Is the price of the bundle reduced by the games I already have?

Do I get nothing special for already owning those 3 games?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens if I activate a product key on Steam for a game I already own?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5698/what-happens-if-i-activate-a-product-key-on-steam-for-a-game-i-already-own)

Comment: Just shooting an update your way. [Steam's policy on partial bundles changed in 2016, and I wrote an answer about it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/330366/136533)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[As of March 2016](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-03-02-steam-bundles-now-cheaper-if-you-already-own-included-games), Steam now subtracts the price of owned games from bundles, so you don't have to re-buy them.

> "Past Complete Packs were sometimes a bad deal for customers that already [owned] one or more of the products in the pack," Valve added. "Either it made bad economic sense for those customers to purchase the pack, or they just felt bad about doing so since it [looked] like they were paying for products they already [had]. The new Steam Bundles system addresses this.

In fact, here's a bundle viewed from my own account:

[image]

And from incognito:

[image]

Note how the base price of the bundle is about $5 cheaper when I'm logged in.

### Packages

However, it's important to note that Steam makes a distinction between ["bundles" and "packages"](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2592234299566324683/).

> Packages are a fixed price - if you already own something in it, you dont get a lower price or a second copy.
>   Bundles will take out content you already own and adjust the price accordingly.
>
> -moistly harmless, Jul 2, 2017

With packages, the prices are fixed, and you pay the full price no matter what. So it would be silly to buy the game and then buy the *game + OST* package. Because you'd be paying for the game twice and only getting one copy.

Before buying the game:

[image]

And after:

[image]

That base price won't budge.

<sub>...I just bought a game to illustrate a point.</sub>

Comment: As someone who suffers from an overly large steam library of games I rarely touch; I can confirm this is true.  I no longer get gifts when I purchase bundles that I already own a game in, but instead get discounts.  Also, the price of your bundle is only 14 cents cheaper (since the bundle has the discount applied), and you'll notice that they % savings doesn't always get maintained when the price drops.  Here you're losing 3% savings.

Comment: @JMac Forgive me for nitpicking, but did you mean 24 cents? `4.84 - 4.60 = 0.24`

Comment: I'm wondering if "BUNDLE's" are distinct from the seemingly more common deals when you get e.g. Far Cry 5 + Far Cry 3.

Comment: @NickT I'm not sure what you mean? The only "deal" I found related to Far Cry 3/5 is [this bundle](http://store.steampowered.com/bundle/5583/Far_Cry_Bundle/), but 1. it's a bundle, and 2. it's only for the first 4 games, and 5 doesn't have any bundles at all. I've heard of bundles being customized per-account, but I can access the bundle from incognito as well, so that clearly isn't the case here. Or maybe I just don't understand how Steam personalizes things.

Comment: @NickT update: I just ran into a "package". The [Steam Forums](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2592234299566324683/) shed some light on this. It's fixed price, which means that even if you already own an item in it, you still pay the full price of the package, and you don't get a gift copy of the game or anything. Maybe you were thinking of those?

Comment: I was guessing 5+3, but I think that was a pre-order bonus if you bought 5. The "packages" or packs or whatever *seem* to be more common and generally where the deals are (spend more to save moar!). With the bundles you mention, are they priced identically if you were to individually add all the games to your cart?

Comment: I think this is the first time I've ever seen someone "buy upvotes"... albeit indirectly. :) Nice answer!

Comment: @NickT Bundles add an additional discount (separate from steam sales) to incentivise buying the games together. For example, in the "Arcade Bundle" Bundle I referenced, the bundle applies a base discount of -50% to the subtotal of all the games. During a sale, this is pretty awesome. The games in the Arcade Bundle without the discount and sales total out to $23.91. With the individual sales, it's $9.76. And with the bundle, it grinds all the way down to $4.84.

Comment: @MageXy I probably would've ended up buying it anyway. I just hope my lack of research before buying doesn't come back to bite me, haha.

Comment: @BradenBest I think it was worth the example, They Bleed Pixels is a pretty good game if you are into pixel platformers.

Answer (score 38):

Steam won't let you buy the *same* product twice (without it being a gift).  For your particular case with the with the Potato Sack Pack containing things you already own, [on the product listing](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/7586/) it mentions:

> #### About this game
>
> Already own one or more of the games in this pack? Not to worry, you can give your extra copy of any game in this pack to a friend.

Extra copies are essentially the same as gifts, and you can freely give them to whomever you want.  The recipient need not have a Steam account, the email Steam sends will instruct them how to make an account.

However, you are by no means guaranteed to get extra copies when you purchase a pack containing games you own; the [Steam KB mentions](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4502-TPJL-2656)

> #### Extra copies are not given in most cases.
>
> Only titles purchased in special promotions as outlined below are eligible for giftable extra copies

It lists a few (Orange Box, L4D packs, Dawn of War II), but obviously if the product page explicitly mentions so, then that would take precedence.  Additionally, the cost of a pack is *not prorated*, regardless of you already owning some parts of it.

For some games at least, Steam will notify you of this overlap (and loss) when you're reviewing (before) your purchase. For example, below, I already have *Far Cry (1)*, so when I buy the *Far Cry* Franchise pack (includes 1-3), I'm effectively wasting that bit of it.

[image: Review screen of Steam purchase]

---

In order to gift the spare copies, in the Steam client go to **Games** >> **Manage Gifts and Guest Passes...**  There it will list all the extra copies you have to give, and you can either give them to someone else (or yourself, if you don't have it).

[image: Steam gift interface]

Comment: Where do I go to see these spare games? I was gifted an indie bundle in the past with duplicates, and thought those duplicates lost.

Comment: @Raven, true, I assumed a bit too much.  Have anyone in mind for Defense Grid? :P

Comment: This answer is outdated as of 2016. Steam bundles now subtract the prices of games you already own. Smart move on their part, cause I wouldn't want to buy a bundle if I had to re-buy games I already own.

Comment: @BradenBest is it? I would think that's the exception rather than the rule. Post a new answer if it's not.

Comment: @NickT Oh no, it's definitely the rule now. [Here's my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/330366/136533).