# Where's my [Classified]?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

As indicated by [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20182/336) I bought the Potato Sack bundle a scant few days before Portal's release. Rather than buying the Potato Sack alone, I instead bought it bundled with Portal 2, as listed [here](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/7852/).

I've been playing a bit of TF2 after spending all of yesterday selfishly swiping potatos, and though I played for about an hour, I did not get either the [Classified] potato hat (gained by purchasing the potato sack), nor the Portal 2 companion cube pin (which should be given out to anyone who purchases Portal before the 19th - I purchased the bundle on the 16th)

What gives? Do I have to do something additional to claim my [Classified] and companion cube pins? (On the other hand, The Resurrection Association Pin, earned for playing every game in the potato sack, *has* been earned).

Comment: Just wait, it happens more or less with every promotional items. Hat .delivery is slow, they are probably "hand-made"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would check again following today's update.

Also, try visiting the Mann Co. store once, even if you aren't buying anything.

Comment: That worked for me. I received my companion cube pin after visiting the Mann Co. store.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a few days to get my [Classified] after they I purchased the bundle (though I purchased it as soon as I knew it gave a hat); you should get yours eventually.

Comment: The potato hat wasn't in TF2 yet when the Potato Bundle was announced as having a TF2 hat, so there's a good reason you didn't get it immediately.

Comment: I didn't get it for a few days after it was included, either.