# What happened to Steam's second hand game market idea?

Tags: steam

What happened to Steam's idea to allow users to resell their copies of games?

It was a hot topic few years ago, but I have not heard anything since.

Comment: Apparently, it is not as dead as I thought, just found a refernce to Steam Trading Beta: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6748-ETSG-5417

For now you can only exchange unopened gifts, hopefully more comes later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're referring to the rumours started by Pachter, they had no basis to begin with. He was just making stuff up.

[Article Excerpt:](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/steam-trade-used-gamestop-exchange,11467.html)

> Before you celebrate about how you may be able to send your digital
>   games back into the Steam stream for someone else to enjoy, Valve's
>   Doug Lombardi killed the notion with the following statement to Blue's
>   News: "Untrue. We've never met with Mr. Pachter."

Comment: So sad :( i hoped it will once be true, some kind of used games exchange in digital form. Actually i did it already with starcraft 2 and others, but those were special deals and I do not want to completely loose my steam account.

Answer (score 3):

You can already [give extra copies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20182/what-happens-if-i-buy-a-game-i-already-own-through-steam-a-second-time/20183#20183) of games you own and get more from a pack (*in [select circumstances](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4502-TPJL-2656)*) on Steam.

I can't imagine why this would ever be an idea considered by Valve, however.  The prices of games tend to go down over time anyways, so if you want it for less money, you could just wait.  Publishers who use Steam would need to agree to this somehow as well, which seems pointless if they can just sell a whole other copy of the game for the cost of a few GB of bandwidth.

Sure, *users* can clamor all they want for it, that doesn't mean it will ever happen.

Comment: While you're right in saying it's not done by Valve, but saying it's unlikely or a bad idea is a bit of a stretch, seeing as it is already done by [other publishers](http://www.greenmangaming.com/).

Comment: It is a good idea for me, i want to give my games away as don't need them anymore.

Comment: I am guessing the rason they don't is because game companies would not like it and pull their product. Major studios hate the used game market. They lose a potential sale.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, it is not as dead as I thought, just found [a reference to Steam Trading Beta](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6748-ETSG-5417).

For now you can only exchange unopened gifts. Hopefully more comes later.