# If I have two copies of the same game, can I Gift one of them?

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if I buy a game I already own through Steam a second time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20182/what-happens-if-i-buy-a-game-i-already-own-through-steam-a-second-time)

I was wondering about gifting on steam. See, I already have Warhammer Dawn of War II Gold Edition (Dawn of War II and Chaos Rising) but Steam has the Warhammer Collection on sale.

If I buy the Collection can I send the copies of Dawn of War II and Chaos Rising to a to friend seeing as how I already have them and don't need them.

I seen on there support page if you have Dawn of War II and but the Gold Edition then you can gift the second Dawn of War game and keep the Chaos Rising one. I was just wondering if it works the same way with the Collection pack.